# Including <queue> in c++ program in Ubuntu OS

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I have a small program that uses "trying to use" `#include <queue>`. I use Ubuntu OS but it says:

```
fatal error: queue: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas why, or what I need to do to make it work?

```
#include <queue>
using namespace std; 


int main()
{
    queue<int> Q;
    Q.push( 1 );
    Q.push( 2 );
    Q.push( 3 );
    cout << Q.front();
    Q.pop();
    cout << Q.front();
    Q.pop();
    cout << Q.front();
    Q.pop(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try the nonstandard backward-compatibility header stack.h? Do you have other std components?

Comment: i am compiling gcc queuetest.c

Comment: Yeap that was it you are geniuses :) thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are compiling your C++ program (which you saved with a `.c` extension) with a C compiler.

This won't work, since you're using the C++ STL (and namespace `std`).

Compile using `g++` instead:

```
g++ queuetest.cpp -o queuetest
```

See the [docs for compiling C++](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_54.html). Consider changing your extension to `.cpp` as well.

You'll also want to `#include <iostream>` for `cout`.

Comment: Please note the difference between `.c` (the extension the OP used, which defaults to the C language) and `.C` (uppercase, which defaults to C++).

Comment: @Ben: Right. I meant C the language, but it's unclear; I'll fix that up. Thanks :-)

Comment: I think g++ recognizes either `.C` or `.cpp` to mean C++ code.  `.cpp` is probably better if your source files might ever be ported to Windows, with its case-insensitive file names.  (The file system is case-preserving, but it's still possible to mess things up.)